# Decide $\overline{A} $ U $\overline{B}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

$U = \left \{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 \right \}$

$ A = \left \{ 1,2,3 \right \}$

$ B = \left \{ 3,4,5,6 \right \} $

a) Decide $ \overline{A}  $ U $\overline{B} $

**Correct answer:**

\begin{Bmatrix}
 1,2,4,5,6,7,8
\end{Bmatrix}

I don't understand that answer. What does  $\overline{A} $ and  $\overline{B}$ mean?

Comment: It's up to you to tell us what it means, right?!

Comment: What? it seems like 3, that both A, B and U have is not included in the union

Comment: Probably $\overline{A}$ means $U\setminus A$ and the same for $B$.

Comment: Surely your book defines that? Typically $\overline{A}$ is the "complement of A", the set of all elements of U that are **not** in A. A= {1,2,3} so its complement is {4,5,6,7,8,9}.  Similarly B= {3,4,5,6} so its complement is {1,2,7,8}.

Comment: $\overline{A}$ means complement of $A$. So everything in the universal set that is not in $A$ is $\overline{A}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\overline{A}$ means that all the elements in $U$ that are not in set A. So, $\overline{A} =\{4,5,6,7,8\}$

$\overline{B}$ means that all the elements in $U$ that are not in set B. So, $\overline{B}=\{1,2,7,8\}$

Now $\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}=\{1,2,4,5,6,7,8\}$

Answer (score 0):

$\bar{A}$ means everything in $U$ that’s not in $A$. So we get $\bar{A} = \{ 4,5,6,7,8 \}, \bar{B} = \{ 1,2,7,8 \}$ from which the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use $\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}=\overline{A\cap B}=\overline{\{3\}}=U\setminus\{3\}=\{1,2,4,5,6,7,8\}$

- When the context in unambiguous $\overline{X}$ designates $U\setminus X$.
- When the context in ambiguous (i.e when $\overline{X}$ designates the closure of $X$ and $\mathring X$ its interior) then $X^\complement$ is prefered.